# iphone switch views with buttons, SecondView over FirstView

Tags: iphone, view, button, switch-statement

to all im newbie developer and trying to create my first iPhone app, *sorry my english not good*

i trying to make 2 views and the second view display over first view, but the second view is not full screen, is 320x400 i cut 80pixels, to see the buttons from the first view... and i making that with  tutorials from one book, but in book he making 1 button on first view and 1 another button in the second view... and i need 2 buttons on the first view, and can't make it. please help me... i think is very easy but i dont know how to..

with this code make in book what i reading

---

```
**FirstView.h**
```

#import UIKit/UIKit.h

@interface FirstView : UIViewController {
}

/*--- declare an action for the Button view ---*/

-(IBAction) goToSecondView:(id) sender;

@end

```
**FirstView.m**
```

#import "FirstView.h"

#import "SecondView.h"

@implementation FirstView

SecondView *secondView;

-(IBAction) goToSecondView:(id) sender{

secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 
    [self.view addSubview:secondView.view];

}

-(void)dealloc {
    [SecondView release];

[super dealloc];
}

```
**SecondView.h**
```

#import 
@interface SecondView : UIViewController {
}

/*--- action for the Return button --- */

-(IBAction) goToFirstView:(id) sender;

@end

```
**SecondView.m**
```

#import "SecondView.h"

@implementation SecondView

-(IBAction) goToFirstView:(id) sender {

[self.view removeFromSuperview];}

And after linking on Interface Builder one button (goToSecondView) on the first view, and one button on the SecondView(goToFirstView).... and i want to make this two buttons on the first view.

***Help me please!*** , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put another button in the first view and move your code of goToFirstView to the FirstView controller. Then, change where you coded [self.view removeFromSuperview]; by a [secondView.view removeFromSuperview];

I suggest you to read some tutorials of how the views and viewcontrollers are designed in iPhone.

Comment: thank you very much!!!, this help me, 

change where you coded [self.view removeFromSuperview]; by a [secondView.view removeFromSuperview];


thanks again :)